# Changing the model field with TextBoxFor and passing the model to the controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with property of the viewmodel:

```
public class FilterModel
{
    [DisplayName("Start")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}")] 
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("End")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public bool ShowActive { get; set; }
}
```

My view update `StartDate` and `EndDate` on the model using `TextBoxFor`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ApplyFilter", "Shipment", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <div class="input-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin: 3px">
           <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      </button>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Filter.StartDate,  new { @minlength = "4", @maxlength = "20", @style = "margin: 3px; border: solid 1px #d5d5d5;" })
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Filter.EndDate, new { @minlength = "4", @maxlength = "20", @style = "margin: 3px; border: solid 1px #d5d5d5;" })
  </div>
}
```

The method in controller `ApplyFilter`:

```
public ActionResult ApplyFilter(FilterModel filter)
{
   var vm = Load(filter);
   return View("Index", vm);
}
```

The properties `StartDate` and `EndDate`are correct updated but property `ShowActive` is always setted with `False`. The property `ShowActive` does not pass its current value in the view to the controller when `ApplyFilter` method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add ShowActive to your view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ApplyFilter", "Shipment", FormMethod.Post))
{
 
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ShowActive)
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed ShowActive on your View:

You can add:

```
<div class="checkbox">
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ShowActive, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "checkbox", @id = "checkbox-showactive" } })
   <label for="checkbox-showactive"> Active</label>
</div>
```

If you want to handle that property hidden to user:

```
@model FilterModel
---
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ShowActive)
```